# Problem with adapting the site for iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iphone

I have some problem with site for Iphone.
http://nlbook.net/reader?book=1&page=1
The text goes beyond the screen size limits.
On the Android everything works good.

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUpNj.png][1]  
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDyNT.png][2]  
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCa3p.jpg][3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css on `.book, body`

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
.book{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: https://sun5-4.userapi.com/6Uu3zHZ2mARkADQ30VfOhhyHSf8MLzTyOym_ig/fYkKM5_Ny1E.jpg

Comment: Can I make sure that the sentence is not cut off and transferred?

Comment: When you inspect in Responsive mode, Im seeing modals on each of your words. They are wrapped in `<a>`. Is that how it is supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, On the Android everything works good, but ios doesn't work

Comment: Hmm....with those modals, it doesn't constitute a fluid flow of characters. Good question.